# 12 players in groups of 4 over 4 games - can they all play together?

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-designs

12 players play 4 games. In each game they play in groups of four, and, within each four, they play as pairs. So, in 4 games each player must have 4 different partners, and *should play with as many of the 12 as possible (in their groups of four)*.  Ideally, by the end, they would each have played in the same group of 4 as everyone else.
Is there a method for this? I tried looking at Steiner systems but I got a bit lost.

The answer to the linked question works for lots of games, but I can't work out how to apply it to just 4.
[Tournament bracket for a 4-player game and 13 players in total](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4014262)

Comment: Does the partnership aspect play any role?

Comment: Good question - they mustn't have the same partner twice, but they can be in the same group of 4 as someone else twice.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, but some comments. Suppose we have such a design in which everyone plays with everyone else. Each person plays in $4$ games each with $3$ other people, so she plays with one lucky person twice and everyone else once. Therefore the $12$ people consists of $6$ pairs each of whom play with each other twice and everyone else once.

Here is a solution without the "resolvable" aspect, i.e., the following is a set of $12$ blocks of size $4$ in a set of size $12$ such that every pair occurs together in a block, *but* the blocks cannot be organized into 4 lots of mutually disjoint blocks.

Consider the set $S = \{0, 1, 4, 6\} \subset \mathbf Z / 12\mathbf Z$. Observe that every nonzero element of $\mathbf Z / 12\mathbf Z$ is represented uniquely as a difference $x - y$ with $x, y \in S$, except $6$ which is represented twice (as $6-0$ and $0-6$). Therefore the set of $12$ blocks $\mathcal B = \{z + S : z \in \mathbf Z / 12 \mathbf Z\}$ have the property that every pair $x, y$ appears in exactly one block, except if $x-y = 6$ in which case they appear in two blocks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is helpful and well explained.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that a solution to your problem exists. Suppose one fixed player is removed from the setup, so each round consists of two games with four players and one game with three players; moreover, every player gets to play with every other player at least once.

In other words, this "reduced setup" meets the criteria of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4705309/generating-groups-without-repetition) which I recently proved to have no solution.

Therefore, our assumption is false, i.e. your problem does not have a solution either.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I would like to ask whether it makes a difference that your proof involved no repetition, where my problem doesn't object to repetition?

Comment: I can't seem to edit my previous comment. Players can't have the same partner twice, but they can be in the same group of 4 as another player twice. I just about follow your proof in the answer linked, and quite a bit of it refers to the Z group that has only 3 people. Does this necessarily apply if group Z has 4 people?